# Could not load assembly error when running dnx web

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx, coreclr

I have created a asp.net web API project using the template from the Yeoman asp.net generator. 
I can successfully get to build it using the **dnu build** command, but when I run **dnx web**, it gives me this error:

```
  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Overlapped, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neut
ral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not ma
tch the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Threading.Overlapped, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.CloseRequestQueueHandle()
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Server.WebListener.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.MessagePump.Start(Func`2 app)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener.ServerFactory.Start(IServerInformation server, Func`2 app)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider service
Provider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider service
Provider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targe
tFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
```

I am using coreclr   **1.0.0-rc1-15798 coreclr x64** on windows 7 x64.
I can run the templates from **https://github.com/aspnet/home**

The **project.json** file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.ini",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Don't mix beta7 and  rc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dnx beta7. Don't mix beta7 with beta8 or rc1 bits